# Android: onSharedPreferenceChanged()

Tags: android

I have a listPreference in Settings in my App. And i have a `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method where i do something if the value was changed. But if user click on the same list item `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` called again. But i dont want to do anything if user clicked on the same row in listPreference... How to handle that ? How to check in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` if the value was change or not ? Thanks.

For example

```
 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    if (key.equals(SOME_KEY)) {
        setResult(2);
    }
}
```

But I dont wont to set result if the value is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better do that in `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sharedPreferences.getString(key,defValue);`

Comment: While this line may answer the question we prefer answers with some explanation.